# Realtek RTL8723be doesn't have good reception

Tags: wireless, realtek

Only when I'm closer to the router, it shows any signal, but when I'm just little far from it, it is not showing wifi routers signals.

Comment: Let me guess, is it a HP laptop?

Comment: Yes.. HP Laptop !!

Comment: Is it easy to access the wifi card?

Comment: Yup ... There's no another error, only that I mentioned above.. And I almost try all the solution present in the internet... but no one method can able to solve this problem...

Comment: I mean physical access, is it easy to replace?  Some HP laptops require major disassembly to get to the wifi card

Comment: I don't know about it. You know It's not a external wifi card & my laptop is on warranty so I never opened it. Is it important to do that stuff as you said? There's also windows inside my laptop, in windows there's no error with my wifi card. Only when I use Linux I will get this error.

Comment: You will have to wait for Larry Finger and the people at Realtek to come up with a solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Ubuntu 16.04 and later, go to Parameter settings as nothing needs to be downloaded

Progress from Larry Finger from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/28)

If you installed rtlwifi-new-dkms from Pilot6's PPA, it will need to be removed with

```
sudo apt-get remove rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Reboot, then

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and then

Parameter Setting

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Test wireless, if no change then

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

Test wireless again, one or the other should result in better reception

When you find that one works better than the other

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=X" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtlbtcoex.conf
```

Where `X` is 1 or 2- whatever resulted in better performance, in the case of Swapnil Sharma it would be

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtlbtcoex.conf
```

Then the parameter will be remembered following a restart

Comment: Thanks it works. But not Completely. I have to use this again and again after restarting my Laptop. 
`sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1`

Comment: WOW... This actually works... seems to have worked for my Realtek RTL8188EE WiFi driver. Thank you so much @Jeremy31 ! This issue was really starting to bother me.

Comment: Hi This worked fine. I faced this issue with Ubuntu 18.04 a few months back and at the time I had copied the new rtlwifi drivers from this link : https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, I started facing this again. This time i just checked if I needed to download the drivers again and found the link is not working. But luckily I ran the command without downloading the drivers and it worked like a charm.  So all in all method is working but link is not available anymore. if Any of you has the repo for these drivers, please post it here. Cheers