# Using Realtek 8732be on a HP Stream 11 is extremely slow

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

I have a brand new HP Stream 11-r001nd. I am able to connect to my network, but it is too slow. Even when I put my laptop and the router right next to each other it's too slow to watch a youtube video (if the webpage from youtube does load at all). On Windows 10 this problem didn't exist.

In this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbglTmowRK4) it shows that using version 14.10 the speed was acceptable. But that version is not supported anymore.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Jun 2016 16:42 CEST +0200

Booted last: 21 Jun 2016 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 26 May 2016 21:56 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Foxconn WLAN Realtek Sanji RTL8723BE bgn 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB NGFF 2230 M.2 WW
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0ace:1211 ZyDAS ZD1211 802.11g
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
mac80211              737280  1 zd1211rw
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,zd1211rw
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.2.5  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6513:6163:ec8d:ccb5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2501 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2526 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1392891 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:375779 (375.7 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"VGV75190BB329"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=66/100  Signal level=66/100  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:19   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       681     1  0 09:51 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

Error: nmcli (1.2.0) and NetworkManager (1.1.93) versions don't match. Force execution using --nocheck, but the results are unpredictable.

Error: nmcli (1.2.0) and NetworkManager (1.1.93) versions don't match. Force execution using --nocheck, but the results are unpredictable.

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VGV75190BB329]] (600 root)
[connection] id=VGV75190BB329 | type=wifi | permissions=user:ubuntu:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=VGV75190BB329
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VGV75190BB329 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=VGV75190BB329 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:thijs:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=VGV75190BB329
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VGV75190BB329 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=VGV75190BB329 2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:thijs:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=VGV75190BB329
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Amsterdam (based on set time zone)

country NL: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=66/100  Signal level=66/100  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VGV75190BB329"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000032f60cab0e4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC '' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=20/100  Signal level=20/100  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000eaf31214f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 440ms ago
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'VFNL-BA1D5B' [AC3]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=40/100  Signal level=40/100  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VFNL-BA1D5B"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000374c72e2c2b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'UPC4419724' [AC4]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=31/100  Signal level=31/100  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"UPC4419724"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000203ca54961
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'walid72' [AC5]>
                    Channel:7
                    Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                    Quality=43/100  Signal level=43/100  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"walid72"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000051a371e5da7
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'TELE2-5D3D07' [AC6]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=16/100  Signal level=16/100  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TELE2-5D3D07"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000002d0d00fd9c5
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[10532.987919] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: authenticated
[10532.990572] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: associate with <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[10532.994114] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[10532.994148] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: associated
[10532.994253] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link becomes ready
[24341.729193] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: deauthenticating from <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[24359.825298] zd1211rw 1-2.1:1.0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from wlan0
[24359.869707] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link is not ready
[24359.876232] usb 1-2.1: firmware version 0x4330 and device bootcode version 0x4802 differ
[24359.919778] zd1211rw 1-2.1:1.0: firmware version 4605
[24359.947673] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[24360.985805] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: authenticate with <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]>
[24360.996462] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: send auth to <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[24360.998389] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: authenticated
[24361.000117] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: associate with <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[24361.003298] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[24361.003335] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: associated
[24361.003403] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Reloading the module:

```
thijs@Portable:~$ sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
thijs@Portable:~$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available
thijs@Portable:~$ sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
thijs@Portable:~$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available
thijs@Portable:~$
```

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it

Comment: I've pasted the outcome of the script in the link paste ubuntu above

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-in-ubuntu-16?s=1|2.2929 about "Required key is not available"

Comment: And the driver installation answer http://askubuntu.com/a/635629/167850

Comment: I tried both, but I didn't succeed... still not working. Do you think after all these tries, I should run the script from steve Roome again?

Comment: I've run the wireless script from ubuntu forums again becouse I can't see any connections anymore from my internal wifi card, after all my tries to fix it. This is the new outcome of it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/18377793/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked at the results of your wireless script.

You have two error messages. `Error: nmcli (1.2.0) and NetworkManager (1.1.93) versions don't match. Force execution using --nocheck, but the results are unpredictable.` This has been reported as [bug 1590335](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/n/+bug/1590335) by another user, but a reboot fixed it for them.

```
[24359.876232] usb 1-2.1: firmware version 0x4330 and device bootcode version 0x4802 differ
[24359.919778] zd1211rw 1-2.1:1.0: firmware version 4605.
```

This appears to show the incorrect firmware is being loaded onto a USB wireless device.

However your actual problem appears to be [Realtek Wifi Card RTL8723be Not Working Properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717685/realtek-wifi-card-rtl8723be-not-working-properly/722904#722904). Follow the steps given in the solution there.

If this solves your problem please click on the tick mark on the left to show your problem is solved. If not repost the output of the wifi script, preferably after resolving the other two errors. The first should dissapear after a reboot. The second wont appear if you remove the USB device before running the script.

I have looked at the results of your second run of the wireless script. Lets look at a few fragments:

```
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:700903 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:388503 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 ??
      RX bytes:956196276 (956.1 MB)  TX bytes:35329540 (35.3 MB)
```

This shows a wireless connection working perfectly and receiving nearly a gigabyte of data. The next fragment

```
    Link Quality=62/100  Signal level=62/100  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:10090  Invalid misc:95221   Missed beacon:0
```

Shows that the wireless adaptor is performing under difficult circumstances. It is as if it is being jammed.

```
SSID                             BSSID                                          MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
VGV75190BB329                    <MAC 'VGV75190BB329' [AC1]>                    Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       yes     * 
walid72                          <MAC 'walid72' [AC4]>                          Infra  7     2442 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
HP-Print-C3-Deskjet 2540 series  <MAC 'HP-Print-C3-Deskjet 2540 series' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
UPC4419724                       <MAC 'UPC4419724' [AC3]>                       Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  31      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
VFNL-BA1D5B                      <MAC 'VFNL-BA1D5B' [AN5]>                      Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2       no        
HP-Print-7E-Photosmart 5520      <MAC 'HP-Print-7E-Photosmart 5520' [AN6]>      Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  14      ▂___  WPA2       no
```

This shows the jamming is coming from an access point called HP-print-C3-Deskjet 2540 series. I would suggest changing the RF channel of either the access point or the printer so they are on different channels. At the moment they are both on channel 1. The only other channels being used are 6 and 7 so you have plenty to choose from.

The printer is acting as an access point because you have pressed the wireless direct button (see page 53 of the user manual). You should have connected your printer to your router following the instructions on page 49 of the manual. The user manual is available online [here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03847745)

Comment: I tried to follow the steps in your solution, but it didn't work out yet.

Comment: Please give more detail about what you tried and what the results were.

Comment: I definitely can't reconstruct everything I did, but I can log it from now on. I tried your solution, pilot6's solution, and today I found this (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261702) on the ubuntu forums, and tried all the sugested solutions in the thread. As far as I remember did all the scripts do a lot without rumbling error or fatal in between all the abracadabra, and some did even say succeed at the end. Nevertheless, it's still not working. I also have no clue how to give you more detail of the current situation.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve! I don't know what happend. Today, I just run sudo apt-get update/upgrade and sudo apt update/upgrade... and tried again if that desired miracle happened finaly... And believe it or not, my internal wifi adapter is up and running!!! I have no idea what made it work. Well, It could be a big blue screen I got in the terminal to create a security key. I needed it to turn off secure boot uefi or something, and after my reboot I had to fill in that password in a very strange way, but "it" solved my problem.

Comment: By the way, that printer access is becouse it is connected to my home network to be able to print from every device.

Comment: How can I change the channel of that printer? becouse if it can speed up my connection... that would be great. (the first time I came back to my question, I was just too excited that the onboard wifi connection worked, even better than my extended usb wifi adapter, so I didn't look any further)

Comment: After I totaly ruined my ubuntu installation by trying out lubuntu and xubuntu layers on top of my ubuntu layer, I had to redo the process. And I can now tell for sure that the given solution at the other thread (http://askubuntu.com/questions/717685/realtek-wifi-card-rtl8723be-not-working-properly/722904#722904) did solve the problem. I did try it on a fresh installation, and it worked perfectly fine!