# Ubunutu wifi slows sometimes down

Tags: networking, wireless, thinkpad

Hello my new Thinkpad has some wifi problems: sometimes is extremly slow(15 - 100 kb/s) And sometimes it has normal speed(2 - 5 mb/s). I have TLP but there I deactivated Wifi Power managment.
I found this post: [extreme slow wifi on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781306/extreme-slow-wifi-on-ubuntu-16-04)

My Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad e470 with Wireless-Card:  qualcomm Atheros QCA6174

Output of Ubuntu Forums wireless info : http://paste.ubuntu.com/23700886/

Thanks in advance