# No Enable wifi option in network menu

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. I cannot see **Enable wifi** option in the network menu. The network controller is unclaimed

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

       03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
       DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
       Kernel modules: wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I am afraid this device is not supported by Linux yet,

Comment: does that mean I cannot use wifi on my device?

Comment: This means what I wrote: you can't use this wireless device on Linux.

Comment: What is your HP model laptop ?

Comment: Until Linux support is developed and released, I suggest that you use a USB wireless.

Comment: HP 15-bs576tx..

Answer (score 0):

On [Realtek Wifi Card RTL8723be Not Working Properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717685/realtek-wifi-card-rtl8723be-not-working-properly/722904#722904), you can find a partially working solution. Also, until it'll be officially supported in kernel, an USB wi-fi adapter (Linux compatible) is a good solution.