# My ubuntu connection is so slow but the phone connection is fine on the wifi

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, realtek

I did a speed test for my ubuntu and the wifi connection is capable of speeds up to 55 mbps but usually, it stays less than 1 mbps. My phone which is on the same wifi has speeds of about 50 mbps. I've tried disabling ipv6, it made no difference so I enabled it. I tried to force disable the 802.11n protocol with

`sudo rmmod iwlwif`

but I get this error:
    rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwif is not currently loaded

So i am guessing 802.11n is disabled already? my wireless card is

```
  sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: d0:17:c2:1c:83:10
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:dfb04000-dfb04fff memory:dfb00000-dfb03fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: b0:c0:90:68:76:0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.50.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:dfa00000-dfa03fff
```

Keep in mind that at home, my internet wifi works fine after hours of finding the right drivers for my realtek wireless card. But at work it is barely working. I got the drivers from this page

[Realtek Wifi Card RTL8723be Not Working Properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717685/realtek-wifi-card-rtl8723be-not-working-properly/)

but instead of pulling from rtlwifi_new I pulled from rtlwifi_new-master. It gave me errors when I pulled from rtlwifi_new

```
cd Desktop
cd rtlwifi_new-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8821ae
sudo modprobe -v rtl8821ae ant_sel=2
sudo ip link set wlp3s0 up
sudo iw dev wlp3s0 scan
echo "options rtl8821ae ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8821ae.conf
```

Right now I'm going to try ant_sel=1 or X to see if it makes a difference.

Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: I don't believe the driver rtl8821ae has an ant_sel parameter to change. Check: `modinfo rtl8821ae`

Comment: @chili555 I checked and ant_sel does not appear anywhere among the parameters....would deleting it make a difference?

Comment: There is only one way to find out: delete it. `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8821ae.conf` Reboot and report the result.

Comment: @chili555 i did the deletion. When i was at home over the weekend everything was fine as usual. somehow the connection here at work is still bad. i really appreciate your help!

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/323

Comment: So it works full speed with the home wifi, but the work wifi is slow, with no other obvious differences in setup or interface? Have you ruled out the possibility of a MAC (or other) based throttle from your IT dept?

Comment: @taifwa but at the same time my phone connection works fine on my work wifi

Comment: It may well be that the routing is differentiating between the two devices, along some bespoke rules. If your company has an IT team, you should check with them first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try another newer version of the driver:

```
cd rtlwifi_new-master
sudo make uninstall
sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ae
cd ..
sudo rm -rf rtlwifi_new-master
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

Any improvement?

**EDIT**: In your scan we see:

```
Cell 03 - Address: xx
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"sdcwireless WiFi"
                    <snip>
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    <snip>
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Ideally, we’d love to see these changes made:

> First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not
>   any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your
>   router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a
>   channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40
>   MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck
>   with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel
>   selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds
>   only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot
>   the router.

As well, we’d love to see the SSID renamed to one without a space in the name, such as  sdcwireless_WiFi.

Usually, Linux drivers are troubled by TKIP; as well, it is quite insecure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Key_Integrity_Protocol

> TKIP itself is no longer considered secure, and was deprecated in the
>   2012 revision of the 802.11 standard.

We hope you are able to convince the company to secure the network.

We also see, in your message log:

```
[ 3313.007137] _rtl_pci_interrupt: 417 callbacks suppressed
[ 3318.009871] _rtl_pci_interrupt: 1732 callbacks suppressed
[ 3323.014813] _rtl_pci_interrupt: 2015 callbacks suppressed
[ 3328.018509] _rtl_pci_interrupt: 2167 callbacks suppressed
```

Let’s try a driver parameter to see if it helps:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ae
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae int_clear=0
```

If it helps, we’ll make it permanent.

Comment: http://www.speedtest.net/result/7173642236.png no sorry still doesnt work. isnt that the same repo i pulled from before? why is it a newer version? i remember it is that link i used.

Comment: You indicated you pulled the master branch. This is extended.

Comment: does this sound more like a problem with the router and IT dept and not the actual computer?

Comment: I'm still not sure. Please run: `sudo iwlist scan` at the office. Obscure the MAC address with xx:xx or some such and then run: `dmesg | grep rtl` Paste both here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KWnXvfCzR4/ thank you!

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: hello! the parameters did not work until I changed the fixed channel to 1.  Everything looks fine for now! thank you so much!!! would these commands look right to make changes permanent? 
```echo "options rtl8821ae int_clear=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ae.conf```

Comment: Yes, exactly. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Hello, on your profile it said you accepted private messages but I dont know how I can send one here. But would you be able to assist with this problem ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022308/rtl8821ae-switch-case-0x1-not-processed