# WiFi unable to find networks on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, linux-headers

I have a notebook Tbao Tbook pro, on which I had Windows10 an everything worked just fine. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and the WiFi does not work. It lets me turn it on and then when I go to "Select Network" gets stuck on "no networks" (I know that there are networks available). I'll include some of the outputs that I've tried in case they are useful.

```
>:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s21f0u4
       serial: 86:95:0b:2a:37:a2
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.107 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:7
       logical name: wlx54c9dfd91d8b
       serial: 54:c9:df:d9:1d:8b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.15.0-23-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.173 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11


>:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

>00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a8c (rev 0b)
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 24
    Memory at 91110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

>00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a85 (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2212
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

>00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster (rev 0b)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at 91118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

>00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at 91145000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

>00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Memory at 9111c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 91142000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at 91141000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

>00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI (rev 0b) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
    Memory at 91100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

>00:16.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #1 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at 91140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 9113f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:16.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #2 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at 9113e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 9113d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:16.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #3 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at 9113c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 9113b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:16.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #4 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at 9113a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91139000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #5 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at 91138000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91137000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:17.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #6 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at 91136000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91135000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:17.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #7 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at 91134000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91133000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:17.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #8 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at 91132000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91131000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #1 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 4
    Memory at 91130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 9112f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #2 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
    Memory at 9112e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 9112d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #3 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 6
    Memory at 91143000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91144000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #4 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at 9112c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 9112b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #1 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    Memory at 9112a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91129000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #2 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
    Memory at 91128000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91127000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #3 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    Memory at 91126000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91125000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

>00:1b.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDXC/MMC Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 3
    Memory at 91124000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91123000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

>00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
    Memory at 91122000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 91121000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

>00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDIO Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDIO Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at 91120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 9111f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

>00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at 9111e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an RTL8xxxxx card on my HP Stream laptop... it would only work if I was really close to the router (less then 6 feet).

I followed the instructions here https://askubuntu.com/a/722904/677112 and it fixed it.

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtlbtcoex.conf
```

(replace rtl8723be with your exact driver name, you can find it by typing: lsmod | grep rtl)

Comment: Does his driver, rtl8xxxu, have an available parameter `ant_sel`?

Comment: yes, it appears to have the same parameter that is available when you load the module, see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342691/realtek-rtl8723au-not-working-on-linux-mint-18-1 ... I guess you could try to move your computer really close to the router to see if it is an antenna problem (or move the router next to the computer).

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's incorrect. Please check:`modinfo rtl8xxxu` There is no such parameter. Now compare: `modinfo rtl8723be`.