# No internet access after random intervals in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless, arp

I use WiFi for connecting to internet using my Ubuntu 18.04.2. It works fine. But, after some random interval of time, the internet connectivity goes down. The WiFi is still on and the device is connected to it(I also verified this by checking the active client list of my router by logging into the router from another device). After the connectivity goes down, I can't even ping my gateway(Router's IP). If I try to ping my router(IP 192.168.0.1), it shows that `destination host is unreachable`.

So, for troubleshooting the issue, I decided to take a look at my ARP table. After running the arp command, I see the following output:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.1                      (incomplete)                              wlp13s0
```

192.168.0.1 is my router's IP address. This is it! the ARP requests are incomplete. This is the problem. But, I want to know exactly why this is happening. I know ARP poisoning is not being performed because, even if I disconnect all other devices and then perform an ARP request after clearing ARP cache, the problem still persists.

Surprisingly, if I turn off the WiFi and then turn it on again, I get my internet access back. This is a "temporary" fix of the issue. After getting my internet access back, if I run ARP request, I get the following response:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.1              ether   My Router's MAC Addr   C                     wlp13s0
```

Can someone help me resolving this issue and tell me what next steps should I perform to fix this permanently?

Extra info:

My device uses RTL8723BE for WiFi connectivity and it has a known issue for having poor WiFi reception in Ubuntu. So, I use the `rtlwifi_new` driver by Larry Finger as suggested in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/722904/925252

Comment: Try to remove the out-of tree driver. Support of this adapter is OK in new kernels. The answer you referred to is 2 year old.

Comment: @Pilot6 If I remove the driver, my laptop receives an extremely poor WiFi signal. Link Quality=28/70 (from iwconfig command).

Comment: Did you use `ant_sel` parameter to fix antennas?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I need to set ant_sel=2 but, this thing does not work without this driver.

Comment: It should work. What does `modinfo rtl8723be | grep parm` show? What is your kernel version?

Comment: @Pilot6 My kernel version: 4.15.0-45-generic

Comment: Output of modinfo:

parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)

Comment: So `ant_sel` should work. Try 1 and 2 carefully.

Comment: I tried both 1 and 2 but, it did not work until I installed that driver

Comment: I would first try turning off the power management function. See here.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on  (Note: use the one in answer 21.)

Comment: @kc1di I tried doing that but, it did not help. And I know that my radio activities are not being blocked in that state because I tried running nmcli and rfkill commands to check the connection status and here is what I got as output:

Output of `nmcli radio` :

`WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN`
`enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled `

and output of `rfkill` :

`ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD`
 `1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked` 
 `3 bluetooth hci0     blocked unblocked`