# Wifi keeps connecting and disconnecting each 20-30 secs

Tags: wireless, 19.10

My wifi keeps disconnecting after I updated to ubuntu 19.10. Sometimes it works for 5mins or more and then disconnects and connects and does this for 4, 5 times then again is active for around 5 mins.
My laptop is Dell Inspiron 5459 and I recently updated my ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.10
I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717685/realtek-rtl8723be-doesnt-have-good-reception) solution but did not work.

And here is the output of executing `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` :

`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

Also in the Additional Drivers, it says it is not installed.
Look: 
[image: Additional Drivers]

Comment: I added the output too,  can you please help now. It is really frustrating, I keep reloading pages.

Comment: You have an Intel wireless adapter. It made no sense to use a Realtek solution.

Comment: `sudo journalctl --follow` in a termnal window will show ongoing log messages, which will help you diagnose this. There's also https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info

Comment: Are you near an aiport or radar? the 20-30 second sweep suggests a rotating transmitter antenna.

Comment: No, I am in a proper room, wifi is just 3meters away from me. That 20-30 sec is just an approximate. Also, wifi works fine in Windows 10, which is dual boot.

Comment: @waltinator I followed it but could not solve through that. I opened Additional Drivers and it says Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 : This device is not working. I downloaded the firmware from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-io/wireless-networking.html and copied it to /lib/firmware and still the problem persists.